# mapped projection with companion object in SLICK

Tags: scala, slick

I have nested classes/objects and want to store (and retrieve) them in a database by using SLICK. I understand that with SLICK mapped projection would be key. Furthermore I use a companion object to map between nested objects and flat structure (to be stored in the DB table). I want to do something like this (simplified example):

```
case class Foo(id: Int, myBar: Bar)

case class Bar(myInt: Int, myString: String)

object Foo {
  def apply(id: Int, myInt: Int, myString: String): Foo = Foo(id, Bar(myInt, myString))

  override def unapply(f: Foo) = (f.id, f.myBar.myInt, f.myBar.myString)
}

object TTable extends Table[Foo]("FOO") {
    def id = column[Int]("id",  O.PrimaryKey)
    def myInt = column[Int]("myInt", O NotNull)
    def myString = column[String]("myString", O NotNull)

    def * = id ~ myInt ~ myString <> (Foo.apply _, Foo.unapply _)

    def query(db: Database, id: Int): Option[Foo] = db withSession { //s: Session =>
        (for { b <- TTable if b.id is id} yield b).firstOption
    }
}
```

But the compilation fails with several errors: "method unapply is defined twice", "ambiguous reference to overloaded definition, both method apply [...] match expected type ?" and "overloaded method value <> with alternatives"

I found this excellent explanation of mapped projection "[scala slick method I can not understand so far](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13906684/scala-slick-method-i-can-not-understand-so-far)" and "[Mapped projection with <> to a case class with companion object in Slick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15175659/mapped-projection-with-to-a-case-class-with-companion-object-in-slick)" but none of the suggested solutions work for me.

Answer (score 20):

Instead of `unapply` and `apply`, you could just pass in lambdas that do what you want:

```
  def * = id ~ myInt ~ myString <> (
    (id,myInt,myString) => Foo(id, Bar(myInt, myString)),    /* from a row to a Foo */
    (f:Foo) => Some((f.id, f.myBar.myInt, f.myBar.myString)) /* and back */)
```

This way, the mapping from table rows to case classes stays in the table definition, and the case classes stay as simple case classes, which isn't too bad.

The other way would have been to not use a case class for `Foo`, but a regular class instead which leaves you free to define your own `apply` and `unapply` in a companion object, like so:

```
// untested code
class Foo private (val id: Int, val myBar: Bar) 
case class Bar(myInt: Int, myString: String)
object Foo {
  def apply(id: Int, myInt: Int, myString: String): Foo = new Foo(id, Bar(myInt, myString))
  def unapply(f: Foo) = Some((f.id, f.myBar.myInt, f.myBar.myString))
}
```

If you want to do `def * = id ~ myInt ~ myString <> (Foo.apply _, Foo.unapply _)`

You'll get case-class-like usage to an extent, but you might miss the other nice stuff
like having `equals` and `toString` for free as with actual case classes.
I'd rather keep the case classes (and their default `apply` `unapply`) so they can be treated as algebraic data types in the normal convention.

The real issue here is that case classes have their own `unapply` so you can't (as far as I know) have a similar method (same name and same arguments) in your companion class. 
You could simply just use another method name. After all, what you want to do isn't 
semantically equivalent to `unapply` anyway:

```
object Foo {
  def fromRow(id: Int, myInt: Int, myString: String): Foo = Foo(id, Bar(myInt, myString))
  def toRow(f: Foo) = Some((f.id, f.myBar.myInt, f.myBar.myString))
}
```

Then in your table schema:

```
def * = id ~ myInt ~ myString <> (Foo.fromRow _, Foo.toRow _)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Indeed I prefer your first solution which works very well. But with about a dozen parameters the entire mapping seems to be a lot of boilerplate. I understand SLICK's Direct Embedding would be more compact but doesn't allow insertions yet. I'm looking forward to see how SLICK will progress in this regards.

Comment: Even if you were able to have `apply` and `unapply` they way you describe in your question, you'd still have to deal with your dozens of parameters anyway right?  FWIW, look at my last edit.

Comment: With a case class and your last edit I get a "ambiguous reference to overloaded definition" error for method 'apply'. Hence, I had to rename the method in companion object to 'fromRow'.

Comment: How to do the first option in slick 2?