# mapping the equivalent of a JPA `@Embeddable` type in Slick

Tags: slick

Is there a Slick technique for mapping the equivalent of a JPA `@Embeddable` class?
For example, if you have a

```
case class Money (currency: String, amount: BigDecimal)
```

that you'd like to map by default to those two column names in every table where `Money` is used as a column type.

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15627981), but as you can imagine, this would get tedious with a class like `Money` being used everywhere.

Comment: any updates on this? I have a similar problem.